# Implementing a “manager” class responsible for creating and storing objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Upon entering text and pressing a button, the GUI should create an instance of a user-defined Dog class and then print that back to the GUI in the textArea below. The Manager class is supposed to be responsible for creating and storing the Dog Objects by use of an array. Currently my code will run but when text is entered and the button is pressed, I get an error saying that: "Dog cannot be resolved to a variable" Any help with getting my code to work correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Manager {
    private Dog[] Dogs = new Dog[50];
    private int counter = 0;

    public void createDog(String name, String breed, String age) {
        Dogs[counter] = Dog;
        counter++;
    }

    public String returnLastDog() {
        return "Dog: " + Dogs[counter - 1] + "\n";

    }
}

class Dog {
    public String name;
    public String breed;
    public String age;

    // Constructs fields
    public Dog(String name, String breed, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;

    }

    public String setName(String Name) {
        this.name = name;
        return name;
    }

    public String setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
        return breed;
    }

    public String setage(String age) {
        this.age = age;
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Name: " + this.name + " breed: " + this.breed + " age: " + this.age);
    }
}

public class LabFour extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public LabFour() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 1, 1));

        // Creates TextField, TextArea, and button components
        name = new JTextField();
        breed = new JTextField();
        age = new JTextField();
        JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        echoDog = new JTextArea();

        // Add TextField, TextArea, and button components to the frame
        add(new JLabel("Name: "));
        add(name);
        add(new JLabel("Breed: "));
        add(breed);
        add(new JLabel("Age: "));
        add(age);
        add(new JLabel("Submit Button: "));
        add(jbtSubmit);
        jbtSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        add(new JLabel("Submitted Text: "));
        add(echoDog);
        echoDog.setEditable(false);

    }

    // TextFields
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField breed;
    private JTextField age;

    // Echo TextArea
    private JTextArea echoDog;

    // Manager Object
    private Manager m1 = new Manager();

    // Listener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        m1.createDog(name.getText(), breed.getText(), age.getText());
        echoDog.append(m1.returnLastDog());

    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabFour frame = new LabFour();
        frame.setTitle("Dog Interface");
        frame.setSize(1200, 900);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Dog` to assign to the array element

```
dogs[counter] = new Dog(name, breed, age);
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems so obvious now. I will accept your answer as soon as the system allows me to. :)